# Componentes xml não são carregados na activity

Tags: java, android, xml, async

Edição:

> acabei de descobrir que se comentar as linhas que ocasionam o erro,
>   ele fica com a tela toda preta... ou seja, não carrega o layout.

Estou tentando pegar uma ProgressBar e um TextView para poder fazer mudanças de acordo com uma AsyncTask. Vale ressaltar que na hora em que o projeto foi criado, a activity principal não é esta, esta (com nome de SplashScreen) foi criada posteriormente (estou falando isso pois sou iniciante e não tenho conhecimento se algo pode afetar, se deixei algo para trás).

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity
     * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/

    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) this.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    mProgressText = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.progressBarTextView);

    try {
        new WSCatalogo91(this).execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

o retorno das linhas onde fazem o findViewById é null sempre.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SplashScreen">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/logoSplashScreen"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView android:text="@string/progressBar" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/progressBarTextView"
        android:maxWidth="400dp"
        android:maxHeight="400dp"/>

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
        android:minWidth="300dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.universo91.catalogo91_android.activity.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
</activity>


<activity
    android:name="com.universo91.catalogo91_android.activity.SplashScreen"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_splash_screen"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>


<activity
    android:name="com.universo91.catalogo91_android.activity.Login"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">
</activity>
```

Comment: Note que no método `setContentView` você faz referência ao layout sua tela de *splash* mas você está tentando obter elementos da tela de *login*, logo não será encontrado e te retornará um valor nulo mesmo.

Comment: Ponha como resposta.

Comment: Não coloquei como resposta porque não tinha certeza, e realmente eu me confundi. Parece que este XML da pergunta é mesmo sua tela de *splash*, certo? Se for isso a implementação está certa, pois a definição do conteúdo com `setContentView` deveria fazer com que você pudesse obter os elementos.

Comment: Sim é ele mesmo.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues acabei de descobrir que se comentar as linhas que ocasionam o erro, ele fica com a tela toda preta... ou seja, não carrega o layout.